# How to add custom attribute in HTML 5 for valid markup?

Tags: html, jquery-validate, w3c-validation

I am using jQuery validation plugin and placed the error placeholder according to design needs. Used following code:

`<label for="fav[]" class="error" generated="true"></label>
<input id="field-11" name="fav[]" value="252483" type="checkbox">
<input id="field-12" name="fav[]" value="252484" type="checkbox">`

But client complained that the markup is not valid. Following are the errors:

```
Attribute generated not allowed on element label at this point.
The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.
```

I am using HTML 5. I know in html 5 we can use custom attributes by `data-{attribute}`. But as `generated` is a jquery validation plugin attribute, we can't append `data-` to it.

So, anyone know how to fix the above w3 validation errors? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Update to version 1.11.1 of jQuery Validate and safely get rid of the `generated` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by simply eliminating your "placeholder"... it's completely unnecessary.  The jQuery Validate plugin automatically creates the error `label` markup as needed.

If you want the `label` to appear before the input, use [the `errorPlacement` callback function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // your other options and rules,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/8gQ7U/1/**

By default the `label` will have `class="error"` but that too could be manipulated with the `errorClass` option.  Point being, **you can fully manipulate the plugin into using your markup without having to manually write your markup**.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"But as `generated` is a jquery validation plugin attribute..."*

Inspecting [the source code of version 1.11.1 the plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js) reveals no such thing.

The `generated` attribute *used to be* part of [previous versions of this plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js), but not any longer.

So if you still insist on writing your own `label` markup manually, you can safely eliminate the `generated` attribute as long as you use version 1.11.1 of the plugin.

**DEMO (1.11.1):  http://jsfiddle.net/8gQ7U/**